# How to cancel a server side streaming call from client side in C++?

Tags: c++, grpc

I have a server side streaming call of sort `rpc ListFeatures(Rectangle) returns (stream Feature) {}`. How can I cancel the stream from client side or close the channel cleanly?

I have tried `context.TryCancel()` it does the job, but is it the correct way to close a channel or cancel the stream?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is one way to do this. The downside to this would be that the server might not realize that the client has gone away until it has done a lot of processing, because the server will only know about the disconnect when a write fails.

Comment: Can you suggest any other safer way?